# gedit R plugin not working after upgrade to 13.10

Tags: 13.10, python, gedit, plugins, r

I recently upgraded to 13.10, and my R plugin for gedit is no longer working.

When I go to gedit->preferences->plugins and try to enable "R integration", I have little red error symbol and a message that says "An error occured: plugin loader "python" was not found"

The contents of the RCtrl.plugin file at user/lib/gedit/plugins is as follows:

```
[Plugin]
Loader=python
Module=RCtrl
IAge=3
Name=R integration
Description=Allows R to be controlled from Gedit
Authors=Dan Dediu <ddediu@gmail.com>
Copyright=Copyright © 2009-2011 Dan Dediu <ddediu@gmail.com>
Website=http://sourceforge.net/projects/rgedit
```

I did `whereis python` and then changed the `loader=python` line to read `Loader=path/to/python3.3`, which is what I found.

I don't know what to do at this point; would appreciate help.

EDIT:  I have also tried downloading the tar.bz2 file from the developer's webpage and extracting it into the plugins folder.  still doesn't work!

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved by uninstalling the existing plugin using `apt-get` or Software Center and then installing the plugin from http://sourceforge.net/projects/rgedit/files/rgedit-0.8.0.2-Gtk3-Python3.tar.bz2/download into `~/.local/share/gedit`.  Basically just download the archive, extract, and copy thie files into the plugin directory from the archive directory.